# How to access Negative float value in c++ Rapid JSON C++

Tags: c++, rapidjson

I am trying to check and store a negative float value, but unable to validate it.
request is like this --> {"longitude":-8.74301,"latitude":42.20938}

```
for (auto & m: itr - > value.GetObject()) {
    if ((m.name.GetString()) {
            COUT << m.name.GetString(); //printed longitude
            if (itr - > value.IsFloat()) {
                COUT << IsFloat;
            } else if (itr - > value.IsInt()) {
                COUT << IsInt;
            } else if (itr - > value.IsUint()) {
                COUT << IsUint;
            } else if (itr - > value.IsInt64()) {
                COUT << IsInt64;
            } else {
                COUT << data type is not found; //this is printed all the time.
            }
        }
    }
```

I am not sure how to capture a negative float value here.

Comment: This may not be a solution because I don't know about rapidjson, but couldn't you just check whether the float is smaller than 0? Something like: `if( itr->value.IsFloat && itr->value < 0)`

Comment: You should check `m.value.IsFloat()`, not `itr->value.IsFloat()`. Your `itr->value` is the whole object. This is not about negative values. Also, what kind of compiler accepts `itr - > value.IsFloat()` syntax? I assume you meant `itr->value.IsFloat()` but this looks wrong.

Comment: I didn't observed this itr->value.IsFloat(), using m.value.IsFloat() fixed the issue.